# How to extract last word from a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My pandas df column looks like this:-

Col1

---

Closed

Closed+Captives

Closed+Captives+Blank

Closed+Sync

Open

Open+Captives

Open+Captives+Blank

Open+Captives+Blank+Book

Open+Sync

Open+Sync+Candle

---

My output should be:-

Col1

---

Closed

Captives

Blank

Sync

Open

Captives

Blank

Book

Sync

Candle

I want this to be done using pandas. Please help me

Comment: Kindly edit your post to include `+` between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After looking at your comment that there are `+` between words.

You can use `.apply()` and split each row by `+` to get the last word:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('+')[-1])
```

Output:

```
       Col1
0    Closed
1  Captives
2     Blank
3      Sync
4      Open
5  Captives
6     Blank
7      Book
8      Sync
9    Candle
```

Comment: quite similar: `df['Col1'].str.split('+').str[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extract`:

```py
df["Col1"] = df["Col1"].str.extract(r'(\w+)$')
```

Comment: Can you share the code which extracts words after '+' sign from a column ?

Comment: Closed would return Closed. Closed + Abcd would return Abcd. Closed + Abcd + pqrs would return pqrs